# Ubuntu (14 & 16) Bash errors with printf loops from input containing lowercase "n" characters

Tags: bash, printf, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, printf-debugging

I have some bash scripts I have been running on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 for well over a year now. Some recent Ubuntu update has broken bash and I cannot figure out how to sort this out.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=myinput.txt
OUTPUT=myoutput.txt
ACTION1="0;"

cat $INPUT | while read LINE
do
printf "\t\"~${LINE}\"\t\t$ACTION1\n" >> $OUTPUT
done
```

my script then loops through the file doing the printf statement as follows but this is the output produced

```
"~jetmo" 0;
"~spamme" 0;
"~baidu" 0;
```

example contents of myinput.txt

```
jetmon
spammen
baidu
```

Input lines containing a lowercase n character gets stripped out ?? 
Am I missing some major change in bash that occured, this started happening a week ago and is driving me insane now.

I have tried changing #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh with same results.

Also tried this method of looping through the input file and still get the same results.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=myinput.txt
OUTPUT=myoutput.txt
ACTION1="0;"
while read LINE
do
printf "\t\"~${LINE}\"\t\t$ACTION1\n" >> $OUTPUT
done < $INPUT
```

Tried suggestion from comments using echo

```
echo -e -n "\t\"~${LINE}\"\t\t$ACTION1\n" >> $OUTPUT
```

and now I get this output

```
-e -n "~jetmo" 0;
-e -n "~spamme" 0;
-e -n "~baidu" 0;
```

Running hexdump -C myinput.txt gives this output

```
00000000  6a 65 74 6d 6f 6e 0a 73  70 61 6d 6d 65 6e 0a 62  |jetmon.spammen.b|
00000010  61 69 64 75 0a 0a                                 |aidu..|
00000016
```

Also changed all variable names to lowercase as suggested by Michael but still getting the same results.

```
#!/bin/bash
input=myinput.txt
output=myoutput.txt
action1="0;"

cat $input | while read line
do
printf "\t\"~${line}\"\t\t$action1\n" >> $output
done
```

**THE SOLUTION**
*The Mystery is Solved*

thanks to everyone, but https://stackoverflow.com/users/96588/l0b0 nailed it on the head. I had an `IFS=$'\n'` hiding earlier on in my script.

I now have this final, better and safer formatting of printf thanks to the recommendations of Nahuel and Charles and it is working 100% ... cannot thank you all enough.

```
#!/bin/bash
input=myinput.txt
output=myoutput.txt
action1="0;"
while IFS= read -r LINE
do
printf '\t"~%s"\t\t%s\n' "${LINE}" "$ACTION1" >> "$output"
done < $input1
```

Comment: Try to check your input file for non-UNIX line endings. It works fine for me on Ubuntu 14.04. You can also replace `printf` with `echo -e -n`.

Comment: works fine for me on ubuntu 16.04... does this work? `printf '\t"~%s"\t\t%s\n' "${LINE}" "$ACTION1"`... also a few suggestions - use lowercase for variable names to avoid clash with env variables, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for proper way to read file, and consider using text processing tools like `sed` instead of bash script

Comment: Thanks Michael and Sundeep. I tried using the echo -e -n and updated my original question with the results. I actually switched from using all lowercase variable names to uppercase when this started which started improving the problems as nothing was working at all. Even the echo strips off the "n" characters from the input. If I post my entire script section which later uses ed to do in place inserts into marker blocks can you help me get this sorted? I have been running these without issue on 16.04 for a year and on 14.04 too, even inside TravisCI which uses Trusty it does the same thing

Comment: Show the output of `hexdump -C myinput.txt`

Comment: Thanks again Michael, here is the output of that hexdump on this simple test file. ```00000000  6a 65 74 6d 6f 6e 0a 73  70 61 6d 6d 65 6e 0a 62  |jetmon.spammen.b|
00000010  61 69 64 75 0a 0a                                 |aidu..|
00000016``` updated my original question with the hexdump output.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Try to run your command in `xterm`.

Comment: @MichaelO., the POSIX spec for `echo` explicitly advises using `printf` instead. See APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: It's already running in xterm `echo $TERM` gives me `xterm` ??

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line` is going to be closer to byte-for-byte accuracy (and avoids inappropriate use of all-caps variable names outside their [POSIX-specified scope](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) of variables with meaning to the OS or shell).

Comment: Charles, I went with printf when I developed these scripts over a year ago due to numerous recommendations and also having issues with echo. Funny thing is this has worked for a very long time day in and day out and now it's giving this weird behavior. Even happens inside the TravisCI environment which uses Trusty.

Comment: As @lobo suggests, `IFS='\n'` is the most likely culprit. (Can you actually reproduce the problem with **exactly** the script given in your question, no IFS assignments or otherwise)?

Comment: BTW, as another aside, `cat input | while ...; done` is both less efficient and breaks your variable scoping compared to `while ...; done <input`. See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: ...btw, amending your script to have a heredoc for the input would make it more self-contained, and thus closer to compliance with the [mcve] definition from the Help Center; right now it requires content not included for others to replicate the behavior you claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if the internal field separator (`$IFS`) contains the letter `n`:

```
$ IFS=$' \t\nn' read line <<< foon
$ printf '%q\n' "$line"
foo
```

This is a fairly common [mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31295227/96588). Here is the correct value:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$IFS"
$' \t\n'
```

Example:

```
$ IFS=$' \t\n' read line <<< foon
$ printf '%q\n' "$line"
foon
```

Comment: That's true if your `n` is on the **end** of the line (with only one variable-name argument passed to `read`), but that doesn't appear to be the case in the OP's code -- unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yeah, their input file has lines ending with `n`.

Comment: I could KICK myself (aarghhh) .... I had an `IFS='\n'` hiding in my script, oh my word thank you @l0b0 .... I really thought I was going mad.

Answer (score 1):

It's safer to use `%s` to insert a string with printf for example if it can contain `%`

```
printf "\t\"~%s\"\t\t%s\n" "${LINE}" "$ACTION1" >> $OUTPUT
```

EDIT following comments, with single quotes in first argument because there is no variable expansion

```
printf '\t"~%s"\t\t%s\n' "${LINE}" "$ACTION1" >> "$OUTPUT"
```

Comment: I'd also suggest quoting `"$OUTPUT"` -- can get an "invalid redirection" error otherwise.

Comment: (And if you switched from double to single quotes for the printf string, you wouldn't need any backslash escaping within them).

Comment: Nahuel thanks for your input here too, can you explain why the `%s` is safer to use?

Comment: Charles please can you show me an example using my printf with single quotes ??

Comment: @MitchellK %s is safer because first string argument is a format specification is not taken literally ; the characters `\ ` and `%` have special meaning

Comment: How would that then work with Charles' suggestion of using single quotes in my printf. I did try your print statement which works perfectly, just wondering why changing the printf statement to single quotes would also be better?

Comment: @MitchellK, `printf '\t"~%s"\t\t%s\n' "$LINE" "$ACTION1"`

Comment: @MitchellK, ...note that there, we don't need to put backslashes before the `"`s, and we don't need to think about what `\t` will evaluate to (whether it'll be replaced with a tab *before* being passed to `printf` vs after, for example).

Comment: Thank you Nahuel and Charles, works 100%. I have updated my original question with my final script format.

Answer (score 0):

**THE SOLUTION**
*The Mystery is Solved*

thanks to everyone, but https://stackoverflow.com/users/96588/l0b0 nailed it on the head. I had an `IFS=$'\n'` hiding earlier on in my script.

I now have this final, better and safer formatting of printf thanks to the recommendations of Nahuel and Charles and it is working 100% ... cannot thank you all enough.

```
#!/bin/bash
input=myinput.txt
output=myoutput.txt
action1="0;"
while IFS= read -r LINE
do
printf '\t"~%s"\t\t%s\n' "${LINE}" "$ACTION1" >> "$output"
done < $input1
```

Comment: Must really thank you all once again, I always pay my dues. The help from Charles, Lobo and Nahuel has taught me so much about printf, I have modified all my scripts to use this new formatting method and they are working flawlessly.